# How to require values in cell if one cell has value

Tags: excel

Appreciate if anyone can assist me to derive a code for this situation.

I am creating a request form with column A to U and rows 11 to 60.

What I want is "when there's a value provided in 1 cell in column "A", when I click my submit button and I missed to populate other or some cells in the same row it should trigger a message to require a value from those cells.

For example, in column A cell 11 (A11) I entered "New Request" as the value, but I missed to populate E11 or G11 when I click submit I should have a message about it.

What makes it harder is that I need to do it per row. Request details are being populated per row.

Comment: Have you tried to code it yourself? If so, would you be able to share your code? And is your request form a userform?

Comment: I tried doing something like If Range("A11:A60").Value = "New Request" Then
If Range("E11:E60").Value = "" Or Range("G11:G60").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please fill all mandatory Fields"

End If
End If -------- but i think im not doing it correctly to apply it in all cells

Answer (score 0):

In simple try following. Then you can modify codes to work dynamically for you.

```
Sub btnSubmit()
    If Range("A11") = "New Request" Then
        If Range("E11") = "" Or Range("G11") = "" Then
            MsgBox "Value Required"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, is it correct to write

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, is it correct to write,If Range("A11:A60") = "New Request" Then
If Range("E11:E60") = "" Or Range("G11:G60 ") = "" Then
MsgBox "Please populate all Fields with asterisk"

Exit Sub
End If
End If

if i want to apply it in all rows?

Comment: You have to use `For Each` loop to do that.